# Is there a way to group variables with the pickerInput function from the shinyWidgets package?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

My data looks like this :

```
A B C

x 1 NA
x 2 NA
x 2 NA
y 1 NA
y 2 NA
z 2 NA
z 3 NA
z 3 NA
z 2 NA
```

What I need is to group each value of A in my pickerInput function

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

x <- read.csv("Example.csv", sep=";")

ui <- fluidPage(
    pickerInput("x", "Pick :", choices = x$A, multiple = T)
)
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I expect to have in my select box is :

x

y

z

Instead of that I get every occurrence of x y z

So how can I group each of those values ?

I manage to have this with the traditional selectInput function from the shiny package but the "Select All/Deselect All" from the shinyWidget function is really interesting for my purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
              accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv"),
    ),
    uiOutput("selection")
)
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$selection <- renderUI({
        inFile <- input$file1

        if (is.null(inFile))
            return(NULL)

        df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)

        tagList(
        selectizeInput("dynamicselctor", "Pick: ", choices = unique(df[[1]]), multiple = TRUE),
        pickerInput("dynamicselctor2", "Pick: ", choices = unique(df[[1]]), multiple = TRUE)
        )

    })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Render your `PickerInput` or `selectizeInput` from server-side is also an option (But normally it should work)

Comment: Works like a charm in this example, but it doesn't work with updateSelectInput. What I didn't explain in my example is that my data is uploaded with fileInput. Do you have any idea how to solve this one ?
Thanks for responding !

Comment: @Henry I don't see why this wouldn't work with updateSelectInput or if the data is uploaded. Applying `unique` returns the unique values, so what ?

Comment: I don't know either, choices = unique(df$A) didn't work for me, I still get every occurrence of A. But I made the change with @DSGym 's code and everything works. Putting the pickerInput function inside a renderUI is a great idea. Big thanks both of you !